# loop through jquery array using the index to return the value

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I have the below jquery array being returned by a PHP server.
if I alert the array with alert(data) it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => john
            [lastname] => paul
            [id] => 123     
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => adam
            [lastname] => james
            [id] => 343     
        )
)
```

I have tried using:
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
        alert(result[i]);
    }

This returns a single character. I need the entire value to be alerted.

for example: John then paul then 123 then adam... etc etc

Thanks as always,

Comment: Try to convert returned result like `result = JSON.parse(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this;

assume result will be the variable which holding all values

```
<script>
    data = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
         alert(value.firstname);
         alert(value.id);
    });
<script>
```

if you are getting this result from ajax make below adjustment.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
     .
     .
     dataType: 'JSON',
     .
     .
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,but I don't want to call the column / field name directly. rather than alert(value.firstname) I would like to use alert(value[1]) or the like.

Comment: Then you can simply add JSON.parse(result); on your existing system just before the for loop and check a @Satpal suggested

Comment: I tried that method also, but JSON will be the reliable method for this